# Ios Map: Getting latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios6

Am trying to read the longitude and latitude when the user touch (tap) on the ios Map place i want to get that particular (user tapping place) place latitude and longitude points.
**(for (e.x) if the user touch the ios head office means i want to show ios head office place longitude and latitude points)**. How can i do this. Any one can help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override a touch handler (`touchesBegan` or `UITapGestureRecognizer`) and then use
`- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view` in `MKMapView`, class reference  [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html). Then add an appropriate annotation to the map using a class conforming to the `MKAnnotation` protocol, e.g. `MKPinAnnotationView`.

So an example touch handler method would look something like:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{ 
    CGPoint pt = [[touches  anyObject]locationInView:self.mapView];  
    CLLocationCoordinate2D latLong = [self.mapView convertPoint:pt toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView]; 
    //add code here for annotation 
}
```

Then add the annotation - this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial should help you with that- there's an iOS5 version on the same site as well.

Comment: hi. thanks for reply. can you please give me any sample code for this.

Comment: I've added an example method showing how to get a coordinate to the answer. You'll need to look at the docs and possibly some tutorials for the annotations stuff- I've also added a link to a tutorial