# How can I get the coordinates when user tap on a Map in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms (PCL project) I want to get the coordinate (lat & long) when a user taps on map but I can't find any tap event in the *[Map](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=N%3AXamarin.Forms.Maps)* class. I think using TapGestureRecognizer class's object will not help in this case.

So is there any technique that we can perform in native platform for recognizing tap and getting coordinate of that tapped area/point?

Any blog post or technique will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Reworded to make the English more clear, please consider adding some more detail to your post, such as other things you've already tried.

Comment: Go [here](https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/17176751-buy-out-mr-gestures-and-include-it-in-xamarin-so-w) to vote that Xamarin add this capability!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented simple extended map control to provide tap location for all three platforms. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/halkar/XamarinExtendedMap). It's pure sample code, not for production, works fine for me but if you have any problems please tell me.

Comment: I checked with Windows phone and it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

At this point I do not believe any of the nugets out there for dealing with a Xamarin abstraction of maps is going to handle this kind of very specific thing. You will probably have to do native implementations and use a dependency injection pattern to make the appropriate calls.

**Interface in PCL**

```
interface IMaps
{
   public GetLatLong();
}
```

**Native Android Implementation**

see [How to get the Latitude and Longitude on Map in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446811/how-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-on-map-in-android)

**Native iOS Implementation**

see [Ios Map: Getting latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978203/ios-map-getting-latitude-and-longitude)

**Calling Your Implementations in PCL**

```
public point HandleMapOnClick()
{
    return DependencyService.Get<IMaps>().GetLatLong();
}
```